# MySQL Joining tables and pulling information to check

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am trying to return a descending list of item types sold within a specified date range.

I understand how to get the amount of Item types and count them, but am stuck with how to link to the other tables. I will put my working code along with psuedo of how I think it needs to be done, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT Item_Type, COUNT(*) as theAmount
FROM  myDB.Item

//LINK order_ID to item 
//WHERE order_ID includes Item_Type

//Link to session
//Find Ses_Date that order was made

GROUP BY Item_Type
ORDER BY theAmount desc
LIMIT 10
```

I have three tables I need to pull data from, the fields needed are shown:

```
Item
PK: Item_ID
Row: Item_Type
FK: Order_ID

Order
PK: Order_ID
FK: Session_ID    

Session
PK: Ses_ID
Row: Ses_date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Item_Type, COUNT(*) as theAmount, Session_date
FROM  Item
left outer join Order 
    on Item.Order_id = Order.Order_id
left outer join Session 
    on Order.Session_id = Session.Session_id
GROUP BY Item_Type
ORDER BY theAmount desc
LIMIT 10
```

The above query will give you the results.

Comment: @Springfox avoid the `,` or comma from the last select field (after session_date and before from)

Comment: Okay, with a little bit of fiddling I got it working more or less. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   i.Item_Type, COUNT(i.Item_Type) as theAmount
FROM     Item AS i
JOIN     Order AS o ON o.order_ID = i.Order_ID 
JOIN     Session AS s ON s.Ses_ID = o.Session_ID 
WHERE    s.Ses_date between @date1 AND @date2 
GROUP BY i.Item_Type
ORDER BY theAmount DESC
LIMIT    10
```

Comment: What does the .* mean in the parameters for the count?

Comment: @Springfox sorry I edited it. I was just using a notation to point out that count(*) has to be fetched from i (for items). Instead we can use a regular column of table i as well. I edited it that way

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `LEFT JOIN` in this case so if you have no matching records on the other table, the value for `Item_Type` would be zero.

```
SELECT  a.Item_Type, COUNT(c.Ses_ID) theAmount
FROM    Item a
        LEFT JOIN   `Order` b
            ON  a.Order_ID = b.Order_ID
        LEFT JOIN   `Session` c
            ON b.Session_ID = c.Ses_ID
GROUP BY a.Item_Type
-- ORDER BY theAmount DESC
-- LIMIT 10
```